# How to create a program in c# that reads serial data via USB

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a device that connects to my computer via USB. It sends a bunch of serial data but I am particularly interested in being able to read bytes 62-65, and placing them in a byte array. I would like to create a program in c# that does this. I have yet to find any good tutorials to teach me this stuff. I'm hoping this will help.

Comment: USB serial adapters are no different than regular serial ports, from your application's perspective.  Open it like any other COM port.  If you are talking about reading the raw USB transport yourself, then this requires a driver.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The documentation contains some example usages of the class including reading bytes from a serial port.